# How to send message to a viewcontroller in another tab

Tags: ios, ipad

I use a UiTabBarController for my iPad app. One of the tabs is a UITableView with favorites. When I klick a cell I want the favorite to open in a viewController in another tab.

I solved it the ugly way by assigning a variable in a singleton and then select the other tab by [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];

In ViewWillAppear on the target viewController I read the value from the singleton and then do all the action.

There must be a proper way to do this. How do I reference an instance of a ViewController in another tab? Is there a way to load another  viewController in a tab?

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the view controllers in a Tab view by using the viewControllers property.

From the docs:

> The default value of this property is nil. When configuring a tab bar controller, you can use this property to specify the content for each tab of the tab bar interface. The order of the view controllers in the array corresponds to the display order in the tab bar. Thus, the controller at index 0 corresponds to the left-most tab, the controller at index 1 the next tab to the right, and so on. If there are more view controllers than can fit in the tab bar, view controllers at the end of the array are managed by the More navigation controller, which is itself not included in this array.

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate protocol for your table view controller:

```
@protocol MyTableViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) myTableViewController: (MyTableViewController *) myTableViewController didSelectSomeObject: (MyClass *) object

@end
```

and create a property for the delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id<MyTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then make the second view controller be the delegate of your table view controller - either by hooking them up in interface builder, or in the app delegate if that knows about both of them.

Then whenever a row in the table is selected, call the delegate method, which will inform the other view controller.